# Outer fluid grid stacked, but inner should stay intact

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have problem on mobile screens with Bootstrap layout which has nested fluid grids. I would like to have the outer fluid grid stack its columns on a narrow screen but the inner grid should stay intact. A demonstration can be found here (**UPDATED**: removed nested container-fluids but that didn't solve the problem yet): http://jsfiddle.net/uLDQM/10/

What I would like:

```
Desktop:
1 2  3 4

Mobile
1 2
3 4
```

But I have:

```
Desktop:
1 2  3 4

Mobile
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

If this would be feasible for your design, here is one possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/uLDQM/9/

I'm using media queries to overide the default behaviour for small screens:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
.span6 .row-fluid .span6 {
width: 48.93617021276595%;
float:left;
}  

.span6 .row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
margin-right: 2%;
}  

}
```

Comment: That solves the problem all right but it's not very maintainable. I have multiple nested rows with different column spans. Of course I could reset them all but hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: Even though their spans could change, will there always be 2 columns in the nested rows?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Some of my inner rows are separated like 10-2 and some 4-2-2-4 and so on.

Comment: Check my revised answer which support nested colums like 4-2-2-4

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your question, but I think the correct HTML for your nested grids is this:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/uLDQM/4/

Note that I've commented out your 2 nested container-fluid divs as below.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 outer">
        <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6 inner">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="span6 inner">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
      <!--  </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="span6 outer">
        <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6 inner">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="span6 inner">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
       <!--  </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem for full details.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A variation where the width of both the inner and outer spans can vary, and there can be multiple nested columns. Wrap each pair of columns which you want on the same line on the mobile display with the .inner div

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/n2RNx/

Desktop display
1 2 1a 2a 1b 2b 1c 2c

Mobile display
1  2
1a 2a
1b 2b
1c 2c

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 outer">

            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="inner"> 
                   <div class="span2">1</div>
                <div class="span2">2</div>
               </div><!-- end inner -->

                 <div class="inner"> 
                   <div class="span1">1a</div>
                <div class="span1">2a</div>
               </div><!-- end inner -->

                <div class="inner"> 
                   <div class="span1">1b</div>
                <div class="span1">2b</div>
               </div><!-- end inner -->

                <div class="inner"> 
                   <div class="span2">1c</div>
                <div class="span2">2c</div>
               </div><!-- end inner -->


            </div> <!-- end nested fluid-row -->


    </div><!-- end outer -->

    <div class="span4 outer">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="inner"> 
                   <div class="span6">3</div>
                <div class="span6">4</div>
               </div><!-- end inner -->
            </div><!-- end nested row -->

    </div><!-- end outer -->
  </div><!-- end parent row -->



</div><!-- end container -->​
```

Comment: This is quite okay and I'll go with this in my software for now if I cannot find a better solution. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't respect the column spans . Also there some strange problems such as when I add a third column on a row, it gets placed somewhere in the middle even though it should be the last.

Comment: _italic_> ...doesn't respect the column spans._italic_ By default Bootstrap collapses the grid into a single column on window widths below 768px so this is happening on the example as well. No reason why you couldn't customise the CSS some more though if it's a problem. Your comment about a third column should be easy to resolve if you can set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate it.