# Stack elements in twitter bootstrap media grid differently

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap when using the media grid if I have 4 spans across a row and then shrink the browser these get smaller and eventually stack as 4 full width rows on top of each other. This is fine but in between I would like in one of the breakpoints to arrange them instead as 2 columns, before eventually arranging theme as one. In other words as default it seems to go from 4 columns straight to one but I want it to go to 2 columns in between. How can I achieve this.

Comment: To start: this functionality doesn't included in Bootstrap, you'll need a custom CSS solution.

Comment: thanks, yes i've just discovered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094472/outer-fluid-grid-stacked-but-inner-should-stay-intact which seems to demonstrate that. I am fairly capable at css but with bootstrap being so large I'm not sure where to start exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using bootstrap responsive. If you are using an unmodified version than all you need to do is create another media query where every div with a span* class takes on the width of 50%. To be completely consistent with bootstrap, you'd want to incorporate the gridGutterWidth into the style too and remove the margin-left from the first-of-type. Do the correct syntax for the media query based on the css/ less/ sass you are using. This if for sass or scss

Here's some sample CSS to get you started:

```
@media (min-width: 794px) and (max-width: 1060px) {
div[class*="span"] {
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
div[class="span"]:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I will try this. I realise though I forgot to mention that I was using the media grid for this part of my project. Im not sure if that makes any difference. Sorry. I have updated my quesiton

Comment: The media grid just means you can define the thumbnails to whatever size you want. I would use them with the default bootstrap grid sizes though just for consistency. Or if you've defined your own grid, then use the sizes of the span classes you created for your media thumbnail sizes too.  The main point here is that you just need to set up a media query to "break" the design when you want it to and then set all span* divs to the 48% width or whatever width and margin combo you like

Comment: just in case it's of any help to anyone else, or if you want to update the post, the exact css that worked for me in the end based on your answer was ( in media query ) .thumbnails > li.span4 {
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  float: left;
 }  ... I didn't find the first-of-type worked out for me so I did an equal margin on each side instead. I also seemed to need to float it left, and finally I gave it a span4 instead of the wildcard that you had so maybe that would be better but for me I just needed the span4 myself

Comment: The problem with doing both a left and right margin is that on the very first span it won't align neatly. That's what the first-of-type is for. Its possible that your CSS selector was a little off. You could also use first-child, but then if you have another element in the container before the .span it won't apply to the .span you are expecting. The float left is definitely needed because divs are default block elements, but bootstrap already has float: left applied to all divs with .span class.

Comment: FYI, when you are using widths and margins that add up exactly to the container width (100% in this case), be careful not to add paddings or  borders as they will take up space and cause your layout to break.

Comment: not sure why but in my case it is actually aligning correctly ... I suppose I must have some other rules affecting it somewhere. Same again with the float but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you want to achieve is changing the responsive nature. For that you have to use the media query @media as mentioned in the above comment by DMTinter.

```
    /* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

this gives you the ability to change the layouts per the screen sizes you can create any similar responsive width.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks yes I know I have to use @media ... it's some idea of what css that I need override that I need to figure

Comment: yes ... but I had mentioned in my question the word "breakpoints" so I didn't know why you were telling me I needed to use media queries ... ;-)