# Bootstrap responsive list positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site with the latest Twitter Bootstrap using the responsive features.

My problem is that I have two lists that appear side by side, but when the viewport width is less than 768px wide they appear stacked despite there being enough space for both of them to fit. How can I fix this?

Also, a couple of minor things: In the footer I have a strange A symbol appearing before the copyright symbol...how do I sort this out? Also, in IE two elements don't appear inline like they do on all other browsers.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AGHicks Homepage</title>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Header -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5 logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.png" class="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 offset3 phone_numbers">
                    <img src="images/Phone_icon.png" class="pull-left phone_icon hidden-phone hidden-tablet">
                    <h4 class="pull-right align_right">Northampton <span>01604786464</span><br><br>Mobile <span>07710537685</span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem1"><a href="index.html"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem2"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem3"><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>GALLERY</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem4"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem5"><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>ABOUT US</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem6"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem7"><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="row-fluid content">
        <div class="span6">
            <div id="homepage_carousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item"><img src="images/Homepage/640x480px-City-&-Guilds.png" /></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="images/Homepage/640x480px-Domestic-&-Commercial.png" /></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="images/Homepage/640x480px-Small-One-Off-Jobs.png" /></div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="row-fluid homepage_text">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h5 class="text_justify">Welcome to AGHicks Building Services website! We are a Northampton based, family run company with over 20 years experience. Hardwork, efficiency and reliability are instilled throughout the workforce and we have gained a strong reputation through word of mouth.</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class"row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 icon_container">
                    <img src="images/Homepage/Map_pin.png" class="grid_item grid_item1" >
                    <h5 class="redtext grid_item grid_text">Northampton Based</h5>
                    <img src="images/Homepage/Quote.png" class="grid_item grid_item2" >
                    <h5 class="redtext grid_item grid_text">Free Quotes</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="span12 icon_container2">
                    <img src="images/Homepage/Tools.png" class="grid_item grid_item3" >
                    <h5 class="redtext grid_item grid_text">No Job Too Small</h5>
                    <img src="images/Homepage/Piggybank.png" class="grid_item grid_item4" >
                    <h5 class="redtext grid_item grid_text">Competitive Prices</h5>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h5 class="redtext centered">OUR SERVICES INCLUDE</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Conservatories</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Extensions</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Window & Door Refits</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Bricklaying</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Driveways</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Carpentry</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Patios</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Stonework</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span6 offset1 lists">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Plastering</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Kitchen & Bathroom Refits</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Tiling</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Fencing</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Fascias</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Garages & Carports</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Guttering</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div> 
   </div>

   <!-- Footer -->
   <div class="row-fluid footer_wrapper">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid footer">
            <div class="span5">
                <p class="footer_text"><strong>Copyright © AGHicks Building Services 2012 - All rights reserved.<br>Registered Address - 19 Bentley Close, Rectory Farm, Northampton, NN3 5JS.</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 offset3 align_right">
                <p class="footer_text"><strong>Web Design Services and SEO from <a href="http://www.benmil.tumblr.com/me">Ben Mildren</a></strong></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

   </div>     
</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.carousel').carousel({
           interval: 3500
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

The CSS is here: http://gw.gd/Ooky

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of posting your entire site, please create a simplified example and that includes only the relevant code and post it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: "when the viewport width is less than 768px wide they appear stacked" That is standard behaviour. From this page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html "Below 767px viewports, the columns become fluid and stack vertically."

Comment: Note that you're NOT using the latest version of Boostrap, you can try upgrading to the newly released Bootstrap 3, which provides a new grid system with support for small devices. Check http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

As @Omega noted, the stacking of columns <768px is the default Bootstrap behaviour. You can override this with some custom CSS though. Here's a post with a similar question: [Stack elements in twitter bootstrap media grid differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548957/stack-elements-in-twitter-bootstrap-media-grid-differently)

Regarding the strange symbol in your footer, start by checking that your header includes:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Good luck!